# Gift this to the people whom / who you truly care

Tags: grammar, relative-pronouns, relative-clauses

> 1. Gift this to the people **whom** you truly care.
> 2. Gift this to the people **who** you truly care.

The usage of **whom** and **who** both goes with the sentence? How do they make the sentence different?

Answer (score 2):

Neither sentence is correct. Each needs 'for' or 'about' - we care **for/about** people. In my opinion, 'give' is more natural for most native speakers than 'gift'. It is certainly far more common.

*Give this to the people for/about whom you truly care*. Very formal.

*Give this to the people who you truly care for/about*. Less formal, but acceptable these days in all but the most formal of situations.

*Give this to the people whom you truly care for/about*. A mix of the formal and informal that is best avoided.
"Because *whom* is unusual in an informal style, it is very rare in clauses that end with prepositions." Michael Swan (2005.452), *Practical English Usage.*

Comment: If I cut the sentence from "people" what then? "people whom you truly care." and "people who you truly care."

Comment: You cannot *care* people. you can only *care **for/about**them.*